# How to read 19bits out of 3 bytes in Swift?

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation, byte, core-bluetooth

I have a Data object with 20 bytes that I'm getting from a BLE device.

This is an example when I `po` the data in the `CBCharacteristic`:

```
▿ 20 bytes
  - count : 20
  ▿ pointer : 0x0000000282889ab0
    - pointerValue : 10779925168
  ▿ bytes : 20 elements
    - 0 : 16
    - 1 : 0
    - 2 : 0
    - 3 : 21
    - 4 : 0
    - 5 : 0
    - 6 : 20
    - 7 : 3
    - 8 : 87
    - 9 : 154
    - 10 : 3
    - 11 : 88
    - 12 : 204
    - 13 : 20
    - 14 : 255
    - 15 : 197
    - 16 : 7
    - 17 : 159
    - 18 : 56
    - 19 : 122
```

Now I have instructions that tell me that on Byte 1,2,3 there is the signal that I'm looking for as 19 bits (0-524288)

So how can I get that signal value?

I would appreciate reading material on how to get this on my own if necessary. I don't have a proper CS background and I'm lost on how/where to even look for this.

Thank you

EDIT (in response to @Sweeper):

These are instructions for Byte 0

```
General state / configuration. Contains following bits:
7 (highest) – Error state, reads 0 normally and 1 if any error in hardware side
6 – button pressed (’1’ – button is pressed, ’0’ – button is not pressed)
5 – USB connected (’1’ – USB is connected, ’0’ – USB is not connected)
4 – Charging/charged (’1’ – Charging, ’0’ – not charging)
3 – Gain of channel A. 2 gains (0 is slower, 1 is higher)
2 – Gain of channel B. 2 gains (0 is slower, 1 is higher)
1 – Gain of channel C. 2 gains (0 is slower, 1 is higher)
0 – Gain of channel D. 2 gains (0 is slower, 1 is higher)
```

And by doing this I can get the expected data for the first byte:

```
guard let data = characteristic.value else { return }
guard data.count == 20 else { return }
let val = [UInt8](data)
let general:UInt8 = val[0]
let error = general >> 7 & 1
let buttonPressed = general >> 6 & 1
let usbConnected = general >> 5 & 1
let charging = general >> 4 & 1
let gainChannelA = general >> 3 & 1
let gainChannelB = general >> 2 & 1
let gainChannelC = general >> 1 & 1
let gainChannelD = general >> 0 & 1
```

Does this help in knowing the endianness of the protocol?

Comment: What do you expect as output for the example shown?

Comment: @Sweeper The instructions says that it should be a value between 0 and 524288

Comment: I know, but what’s the exact value you expect for the data shown (if you were to work this out by hand)? From your answer we can figure out the endianness and a bunch of other things.

Comment: @Sweeper oh, unfortunately I don't have that information... I could probably ask the extra information needed from the firmware developer. But it takes a while to get answers because they are in Asia (I'm in the US). Besides the endianness, what other information is needed? So that I can ask everything at once.

Comment: Does byte 1 mean the “first byte” or the “byte at index 1”? Are the 5 bits that are discard the most or least significant bits?

Comment: @Sweeper please check my edit to see if it helps answer your question

Comment: The new info doesn't tell me the endianness, but it does tell me that there is a byte 0, which means that you can try the two solutions in dasblinkenlight's answer with `let a = val[1]`, `let b = val[2]`, `let c = val[3]`. Note that `((int)x)` means `Int(x)` in swift, and you probably need to convert `a` or `c` to `Int` as well.

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data comes from multiple bytes, the answer depends on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) implied by the protocol. These 19 bits use two full bytes and three bits in a third byte.

If these three bytes are stored in unsigned 8-bit variables `a`, `b`, and `c`, the value would be either

```
Int(a) << 11 + Int(b) << 3 + Int(c) & 0x07
```

or

```
Int(c) << 11 + Int(b) << 3 + Int(a) & 0x07
```

values for `a` `b` and `c` would come either from bytes 1, 2, and 3 or bytes 3, 2, 1, depending on the order specified in the protocol.

**Note:** Expression `x & 0x07` means "three lower bits", because `0x07` hex is `00000111` in binary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you explain why are you using the << operators?

Comment: @Jan `<<` operator is used to put bits of the original number in their proper place inside the result. Top eight bits need to be shifted left 11 times in order to align with the top eight bits of the 19-bit result. The next eight bits need to be shifted three times, and the final three bits don't need shifting at all.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. One more if you don't mind. Why are you converting the UInt8 to Int? Ahh, I think I got it... 19bits don't fit inside a UInt8. It would be the same to convert them to Int or UInt32 right?